# Parallelising Transformer model inference due to large batch sizes

Tags: parallel-processing, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model, huggingface

I have trained a text classification model using the HuggingFace library. The task is to classify bank transaction descriptions into one of 16 categories.

During training, my batch size was 32. However, now at inference time, all transactions for a single bank account must be classified at a time. Some accounts have thousands of transactions, meaning at inference, the model is recieiving batches much larger than it did during training (1000s as opposed to 32). This is making inference much slower than we would like (~15s per 1000 transactions). To make matters worse, right now I cannot deploy the service on a GPU instance due to cost constraints, so the model is only running on CPU(s).

Are there any options for improving inference time? Is it possible to split each bank accounts' transactions into smaller batches and pass each batch to copies of the model in parallel?

Comment: I could be wrong (apologies if so), but this question seems more on topic for e.g., [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).